# Disassembly or run-time function address?

Tags: x86, disassembly

I have a simple program written in C which outputs the memory address of a specific function. When running this program, the output is: `0x00401334`. Going to that memory location with a real-time memory editor and disassembler I can prove the function is there. The problem is, when disassembling the Windows executable file instead of the process (with a disassembling library such as diStorm), the same function seems to be at `0x00400734`.

What's happening? Is there any way to get `0x00401334` from `0x00400734`?

Comment: Could you please post the code you use (for both finding memory address of a funcion and executable which contains the function)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @HansPassant The function is always at `0x00401334`.

Comment: Are you sure they're the *exact* same function? And one of them isn't just a stub to jump to the other?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yes, I'm sure!